# What is the probability that ant will be on square $S$

Tags: probability

Plane is filled with squares which sides are parallel and have equal length. Each square is black or gray. An ant is placed on one black square. Ant can walk only on black squares and cannot walk diagonally. Let $A$ be the set of all black squares the ant can reach. What is the probability that ant will be on square $S\in A$ after $n\to\infty$ moves?

I came up with this question after solving some other math problem. The main question is what does the probability of square $S$ depend on?
Firstly, I noticed that we can split problem into $4$ cases:
$1.$ If square $S$ has no common sides with gray squares, ant can enter this square from $4$ different sides, so the probability is maximal.
$2.$ If square $S$ has $1$ common side with gray square, ant can enter $S$ from $3$ different sides, so the probability is less than in the first case.
$3.$ If square $S$ has $2$ common sides the probability is even smaller than in the second case.
$4.$ Is square $S$ has $3$ common sides the probability is minimal.

Let $A_m\subset A$ be the set of all squares from $A$ which have $m$ common sides with gray squares. Now, I wonder if all squares from one of these $4$ groups have same probability. For example, if square $S_1\in A_0$ have common sides only with squares from $A_0$ and square $S_1\in A_0$ have only common sides with squares from $A_1$, do squares $S_1$ and $S_2$ have same probability? At first, I thought that $S_1$ and $S_2$ must have different probabilities, because their surrounding squares have different probabilities. I couldn't prove it mathematically, so I made a computer program. After a few million moves, it looks like I was wrong, because all squares from one group have almost the same probability. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tzerw.png) is how it looks.

I couldn't find mathematical way to solve this problem. My question is does the probability depends only on one of these $4$ groups where the given square $S$ belongs. If yes, how we can write the probability in terms of $\left|A_0\right|,\left|A_1\right|,\left|A_2\right|,\left|A_3\right|$ if we know in which group is $S$. If not, can we prove it.

Comment: Assuming that at each step the ant chooses with equal probability each available square to move on it and that the total number of squares the ant can move to is finite and that no periodicity comes in the way, the probability that the ant is on a given square is asymptotically proportional to the degree of this quare, that is, to the number of its neighbor squares. This is done in the first chapters of most lectures on finite (reversible) Markov chains.

Comment: @Did: But of course in this case, periodicity does come in the way :-)

Comment: @joriki Hmmm, yes since one can only move to a square with a side in common, these chains all have period 2.